# How to convert percent 56.67% (string data type) as float64

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to convert data which is shown as 56.67% (string data type). I need to convert it as FLOAT64. I am unable to do it. Can anyone help please.

Comment: Clarify what is expected output

Comment: I want to get 0.5667

Comment: This extremely simple! Have you tried something by yourself? Show us your efforts.

Comment: I used cast(data as Float64) as data. but it shown an error

Comment: Ok. So what was the next try? Or you just gave up?

Comment: SELECT data FROM t1 where safe_cast(data as float64) is null and
     data is not null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(data, '%', '') AS Float64)/100
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives:

```sql
SELECT SAFE_CAST(x AS FLOAT64)
  , CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'[0-9\.\-]*') AS FLOAT64)
  , CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'[0-9\.\-]*') AS FLOAT64)/100
  , CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'[0-9\.\-]*') AS NUMERIC)/100
FROM (
  SELECT "56.67%" x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "1.001%" 
)
```

Results:

```
null
56.67
0.5667
0.5667

null
1.001
0.010009999999999998
0.01001
```

As seen above, FLOAT64 can exhibit some "strange" behaviors, and NUMERIC can help in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

In order to further contribute to the community, in addition to Felipe Hoffa and Mikhail Berlyant answers. I will propose a slight variation for their answers.

BigQuery supports User Defined Functions (UDF) which allows you to create a function using SQL or JavaScript. It is very useful when you need to pass the columns as input, perform some actions and return a result as a value. The below approach uses UDF and [REGEXP_EXTRACT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) builtin method,

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION format_float(x STRING) AS (
CAST(regexp_extract(x, r'.*[^\%]') as float64)/100
);

with data as (
select "55.58%" as percentage UNION ALL
select "60.01%" as percentage
)

select format_float(percentage) as new_percentage from data
```

and the output,

```
Row new_percentage
1   0.5558
2   0.6001
```

Notice that, the function ***format_float*** is used within the select. Also, the regex expression uses **.*** plus ***negative look ahead***, which means that it will match any character apart from the ***%*** symbol. Then the value is casted to *float64* and divided by 100 in order to be formatted accordingly.

*Note: you can wrap any of the other provided answers in a UDF, following the same above syntax,if you desire.*